# How to refresh uitableview/nsmutablearray after adding object to underlying nsmanagedobjectcontext

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a basic UITableViewController that displays a list of schools, fetched from a simple two-entity core data repository.  The tableview is bound to an NSMutableArray of schools that is loaded from an NSManagedObjectContext.

I added a "add new school" button which presents the user with a form for adding a new school.  When the user adds the new school and clicks "save", I save the new school object to the NSManagedObjectContext and pop the "add school" view from the navigation stack.  I am sent back to the original uitableview and the new school IS NOT in the list.

I know that I need to refresh the tableview, upon return, but am unsure how.  NOTE: if I exit the simulator and run the program again, the new school record appears, so I know it is getting added properly to the underlying store.

Pretty sure I need to implement an NSFetchedResultsController but that seems like a TON OF CODE for what seems to be something quite straightforward.

If NSFetchedResultsController is the only way, can someone direct me to a tutorial or a code listing that may show this flow?

Many thanks.

Phil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reloading the data in your viewWillAppear method:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.tableView reloadData]
}
```

PS: I'd still recommend you look in to using a fetched results controller. A lot of the code is boiler plate and you won't normally need to touch it.

Comment: Thanks, Rog.  I did actually find a decent tutorial [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller).  I got it working pretty quickly with the fetchedresultscontroller.  Thanks, man!